# Reeboks custom shoe design functionality. how it works?

Tags: html, css, web

I am new to web designing & development. I stuck with the designing UI for customizing shoes like Reebok does on it's site [link is here...](http://shop.reebok.com/us/content/custom-mens-shoes).

I tried searching on web but I don't have any idea what to search.
 Still I got something i.e. (Referring to above link)

- Actual rotation is having 20 images of different angles, gets change with (mouse)cursor movement.
- Color customization pursuit through image mapping to different sections of Item and applying colors to that mapping.

Functionality I want to Implement consists:

- Item(Image) color should be customizable.
- Item(Image) should rotate with reference to cursor movement.
- Item(Image) mapping colors should stick to it's area.

any Help will be appreciated.. thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad, it's not very likely that you'll get a definitive answer to this question

Comment: I basically not looking for code but for any example or just plain theory that I can refer and guide me to the right direction.

Comment: i assume it is a flash file which is embedded into the web page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is image-maps based, appear to be using a product from a company called "Fluid Retail" from here:

http://www.fluidretail.com/solutions-overview/product-configurators/

**UPDATE**

If I were writing this from scratch it I'd probably ignore the rotating aspect for now and concentrate on getting the color customisation bit right first.

If you had SVG versions of your products that would be a good starting point.

You could then convert your [SVG to image maps](http://davidlynch.org/blog/2008/03/creating-an-image-map-from-svg/) or maybe do something equivalent with [Raphel JS](http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html).  You can find lots of JavaScript color pickers around and could integrate one of these with your product image customisation tool.

Once you've implemented the code to read and remember the color choices, transitioning to different displays of your product images should be achievable.

An image map JavaScript library like [ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) could also be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :)  it's same one reebok site using, But how can I do it myself. any idea ???? Above I mentioned the things I figured out stuck with hat rotation after color applied to mapping, when cursor moves mapping color gets disturbed.?